# Process Returned -1073741819 (0xc0000005) Code::Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm kind of new to programming C with Code::Blocks(Version 12.11), started this semester in my college, but I manage.

I recently learned in class about pointers, memory allocation and dynamic arrays(none are my forte), and I incorporated them in my program(and it compiles)

Now the problem comes when I run the Program and go to Menu -> Add a Product, the program terminâtes when I input a price and I receive "Process Returned -1073741819 (0xc0000005)".
I did some research and found out it's an access violation but I don't really understand how to correct it.

Regards

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define maxCharName 64
#define maxCharUserPass 8
#define maxCharId 5

// Product Structure
typedef struct{
    char name[maxCharName];
    char idCode[maxCharId];
    float price;
    float stock;
}product;

// DataBase of Products
typedef struct{
    int sizeT;
    product *array;
} TProducts;

TProducts a;


// Press any Key on the Keyboard to Proceed
void pressKeyToContinue(){
    puts("\n\n\n     Please Press any Key to Continue...");
    getchar();
}

// Start Page
void startPage(){
    puts("\n\n\n                      -- Welcome to WeePro Manager --\n\n");
    puts("                             -- Version 1.0 --\n\n\n\n");
    puts("                    -- Developped By: Nick --");

    pressKeyToContinue();
    system("cls");
    }

// Program Terminator
void shutdown(){
    puts("\n\n\n      Good-Bye");
    pressKeyToContinue();               // Awaits User Input
    exit(0);
}

// Asks User Information for Verification
int userLogin(){
    char userName[maxCharUserPass] = "WPuser";
    char inputUserName[maxCharUserPass];

    char passWord[maxCharUserPass] = "12345";
    char inputPassWord[maxCharUserPass];

    printf("Username?     ");
    scanf("%s",inputUserName); fflush(stdin);

    printf("Password?     ");
    scanf("%s", inputPassWord); fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");

    if((strcmp(userName, inputUserName) == 0)&&(strcmp(passWord, inputPassWord) == 0)){
        return 1;
    }else{ return 0;}
}

// Lists All Products With their Respective Information
void listAll(){
    int idx = 0;
    puts("List:");
    while((idx < a.sizeT)&&(a.array[idx].name != NULL)){
        printf(":::%s ( id: %s )", a.array[idx].name, a.array[idx].idCode);
        printf("Price: %6.2f eur/g", a.array[idx].price);
        printf("Stock: %6.2f g", a.array[idx].stock);

        idx++;
    }

    pressKeyToContinue();
    system("cls");
}

// Input Product ID Code
char* inputIdCode(){
    char* tempIdCode;
    puts("ID Code?");
    scanf("%s", tempIdCode);

    system("cls");
    return tempIdCode;
}

// Search By ID Code
int searchIdCode(){
    int idx = 0;
    char* tempIdCode;
    tempIdCode = inputIdCode();
    do{
        if(strcmp(a.array[idx].idCode, tempIdCode) == 0){
            return idx;
        }else{
            idx++;
        }
    }while(idx < a.sizeT);

    puts("No Product With Such an ID Code!");
    return -1;
}



// Input Product Name
char *inputProductName(int length){
    char name[maxCharName];

    puts("Product Name?");
    scanf("%s", name); fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");
    return name;
}

// Input Product Price
float inputProductPrice(int length){
    float price;

    puts("Product Price?");
    scanf("%f", price); fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");
    return price;
}

// Input Product Stock
float inputProductQuantity(int length){
    float quantity;

    puts("Product Stock?");
    scanf("%f", quantity); fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");
    return quantity;
}


/////////////////
// Add Product //
/////////////////

// New Product Adder
void addProduct(){
    char* tempStr;
    float temp;

    if(a.sizeT == 0){
        a.sizeT = 1;
        a.array = (product*)malloc((a.sizeT)*sizeof(product));
    }else{
        a.sizeT++;
        a.array = (product*)realloc(a.array, (a.sizeT)*sizeof(product));
    }

    tempStr = inputProductName(a.sizeT);
    strcpy(a.array[a.sizeT].name, tempStr);
    temp = inputProductPrice(a.sizeT);
    temp = inputProductQuantity(a.sizeT);

    system("cls");
}

void transaction(){}


////////////////////
// Delete Product //
////////////////////

// Delete Product
void deleteProduct(){
    int idx, idxPro;
    char* tempIdCode;

    puts("Delete Which Product?\n");
    tempIdCode = inputIdCode();
    idxPro = searchIdCode(tempIdCode);

    idx = idxPro + 1;
    while(idx < a.sizeT){
        a.array[idx] = a.array[idx+1];
        idx++;
    }
    a.array = realloc(a.array, (a.sizeT-1)*sizeof(product));
}

//Product Information Modifier
void modifyProduct(){
    char choice;
    int tabLength;
    do{
        puts("Modify What?\n");
        puts("   -> [N]ame\n");
        puts("   -> [P]rice\n");
        puts("   -> [S]tock\n\n");
        puts("   -> [R]eturn to Previous Menu");                    // Prints the Menus' Options

        scanf("%c", &choice);
        choice = toupper(choice);                               // Save Users' Choice And Up Case
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(choice){
            case 'N':
                    system("cls");
                    tabLength = searchIdCode();
                    inputProductName(tabLength);
                    break;
            case 'P':
                    system("cls");
                    tabLength = searchIdCode();
                    inputProductPrice(tabLength);
                    break;
            case 'S':
                    system("cls");
                    tabLength = searchIdCode();
                    inputProductQuantity(tabLength);
                    break;
            case 'R':
                    system("cls");
                    returnToMenu2();
                    break;
            default:
                puts("Something Went Wrong!\n");
                pressKeyToContinue();
                system("cls");
        }

    }while(choice != 'o');
}

// Sub-Menu Interface
void menu(){
    char choice;
    do{
        puts("Please Make Your Selection.\n");
        puts("   -> [A]dd a New Product\n");
        puts("   -> [M]odify a Product\n");
        puts("   -> [D]elete a Product\n\n");
        puts("   -> [R]eturn to Main Menu");                    // Prints the Menus' Options

        scanf("%c", &choice); fflush(stdin);
        choice = toupper(choice);                               // Save Users' Choice And Up Case

        switch(choice){
            case 'A':
                    system("cls");
                    addProduct();
                    break;
            case 'M':
                    system("cls");
                    modifyProduct();
                    break;
            case 'D':
                    system("cls");
                    deleteProduct();
                    break;
            case 'R':
                    system("cls");
                    returnToMenu1();
                    break;
            default:
                    puts("Something Went Wrong!\n");
                    pressKeyToContinue();
                    system("cls");
        }
    }while(choice != 'o');
}

// Return To Ma

> Blockquote

in Menu
void returnToMenu2(){
    menu();
}

// Main Menu
void controlPanel(){
    char choice;
    do{
        puts("Please Make Your Selection.\n");
        puts("   -> [T]ransaction\n");
        puts("   -> [M]enu\n");
        puts("   -> [L]ist\n");
        puts("   -> [S]hutdown");                                        // Prints the Panels' Options

        scanf("%c", &choice); fflush(stdin);
        choice = toupper(choice);                                   // Save Users' Choice And Up Case

        switch(choice){
            case 'T':
                    system("cls");
                    transaction();
                    break;
            case 'M':
                    system("cls");
                    menu();
                    break;
            case 'L':
                    system("cls");
                    listAll();
                    break;
            case 'S':
                    system("cls");
                    shutdown();
                    break;
            default:
                    puts("Something Went Wrong!\n");
                    pressKeyToContinue();
                    system("cls");
        }
    }while(choice != 'o');
}

// Return To Main Menu
void returnToMenu1(){
    controlPanel();
}


int main(){
    int loginSuccess=1;

    //loginSuccess = userLogin();

    switch(loginSuccess){
    case 0:
        shutdown();
        break;

    case 1:
        startPage();
        controlPanel();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: SideNote: Have you considered actually *returning* something from `main()` ?

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin);`. It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Don't use fflush(stdin)? Our teacher told us to always put a fflush after a scanf... Guess I'm gonna start reading tutorials on the net.

Comment: Also, don't use `system()`. It's, especially in this case, like using a bulldozer to open your front door. See this for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/

Answer (score 7):

An attempt is being made to write to randon memory, via the uninitialized pointer `tempIdCode`:

```
char* inputIdCode(){
    char* tempIdCode;
    puts("ID Code?");
    scanf("%s", tempIdCode);

    system("cls");
    return tempIdCode;
}
```

You need to allocate memory for `tempIdCode` before attempting to write to it. You must use `malloc()` here (and not return the address of a local array):

```
char* tempIdCode = malloc(20);
if (tempIdCode)
{
    /* The format specifier "%19s" instructs scanf()
       to read at most 19 characters, one less than
       allocated to allow for terminating null character
       written by scanf(), to prevent potential buffer
       overrun. */
    scanf("%19s", tempIdCode);
}
```

The caller of the function must explicitly check for a return `NULL` pointer. The caller must also `free()` the allocated memory.

Comment: +1 He's lucky it faults early and doesn't just keep right on chugging into undefined behavior writing to random process memory (which it may do in a release build anyway).

Comment: Thank you hmjd, I see I gotta pay a lot more attention to initializing those pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a killer:

```
// Input Product Name
char *inputProductName(int length){
  char name[maxCharName];

  puts("Product Name?");
  scanf("%s", name); fflush(stdin);

  system("cls");
  return name;
}
```

The reference returned by this function points to an already freed block of memory on the stack, as `char name` is only valid as long the program is inside the function `name` is declared in.

When leaving the function `name` is freed automagically, so any dereferencing of the function's result leads to UB, as it most propably will be accessing unallocated memory.

To solve this you might like to pass in a buffer, where to read the data into:

```
// Input Product Name
char * inputProductName(int length, char * name){
  puts("Product Name?");
  scanf("%s", name); fflush(stdin);

  system("cls");
  return name;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
// New Product Adder
void addProduct(){
  char* tempStr;
  float temp;

  if(a.sizeT == 0){
    a.array = malloc((a.sizeT)*sizeof(product));
  }else{
    a.array = realloc(a.array, (a.sizeT)*sizeof(product));
  }

  a.sizeT++;

  inputProductName(a.sizeT, a.array[a.sizeT].name);

  ...
```